# Largest number of points one can pick in finite projective space without getting three on a line

Tags: co.combinatorics, projective-geometry, enumerative-combinatorics, enumerative-geometry, finite-geometry

Consider the projectivization $\mathbb P\mathbb F_p^n$ of $\mathbb F_p^n$. How large a set $B \subseteq \mathbb P \mathbb F_p^n$ can I pick so that no three points of $B$ lie on the same line?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The term for such sets is "caps".  The problem you ask was posed by Bose ("Mathematical theory of the symmetrical factorial design", *Sankhyā* **8** (1947) 107–166), and is important in relation to coding theory: see Hill, *A first course in coding theory* (1986), around figure 14.9.  At least at the time of Hill's book from which the following values are taken, the maximal size was known just for $p=2$ (it is $2^n$), for $n=2$ (it is $p+1$ for $p$ odd, $p+2$ for $p$ a power of $2$), for $n=3$ (it is $p^2+1$) and in the further cases $(n,p)=(4,3)$ and $(n,p)=(5,3)$ (where it is $20$ and $56$ respectively).  (Some of these results are due to Bose himself.)

**PS:** It might also be worth while to point out that for $n=2$, caps are also known as "arcs", and a theorem of B. Segre states that (for $p$ odd), an arc of maximal size (also, "oval") is necessarily a conic.

Comment: Thank you! A great answer. Is anything non-trivial known about upper bounds?

Comment: @user193072 [This paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00022-002-8590-8) (Storme, Thas & Vereecke, "New Upper bounds for the sizes of caps in finite projective spaces" *J. Geometry* **73** (2002) 176–193) seems to be about this, although I will admit that this is just what Google turned up and I looked no further than the abstract).

Comment: Yes that paper is about the same things. $PG(n,q)$ is what the OP calls "$\mathbb{PF}_q^n$". See also this very recent paper from JA Thas https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.01097

Comment: Also worth noting if you want to search for papers, that often they are called k-arcs (for n=2) or k-caps (for n > 2).